# using a macro function in a file sublime text 2

Tags: macros, sublimetext2

Say there is a macro I want to use that will add a header to the current file I'm in.
Is there a plugin that allows me to declare a macro and use it inside the text?

Example:

Macroname: css title

Callerid: !cssTitle

so when I type !cssTitle into my file and hit enter it displays:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
[Insert Title]
\*------------------------------------*/
/*
[Insert section title]  [Insert description]
*/
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the built in macro functionality for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using the build in snippet function for this. It allows you to do whatever you just required without installing an additional plugin.

Sublime text > Tools > New Snippet:

```
<snippet>
<content>
<![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]>
</content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

Yours would look like:

```
<snippet>
<content>
<![CDATA[
/*------------------------------------*\
[$1] Insert Title
\*------------------------------------*/
/*
[$2] Insert section title  [$3] Description
*/
]]>
</content>
<tabTrigger>!cssTitle</tabTrigger>
<scope>text/css</scope>
</snippet>
```

Of course you can feel free to change it however you would like. Also a `<scope />` is not necessary. You can remove it if you like or  it.

Save as > cssTitle.sublime.snippet

Sublime Text 2 > Packages > CSS > (Save here).

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. I am new to sublime, and trying to figure everything out. Thanks.